# How to save filters or outcome after filtering DataTables using searchPane

Tags: javascript, r, datatables

I am using searchPane extension of DT which An R interface to the DataTables library

if I build a dataTable with a searchPane using the following code:

```
library(DT)
datatable(
    iris,
    options = list(dom = 'Pfrtip', columnDefs = list(list(
        searchPanes = list(show = TRUE), targets = 1:4
    ))),
    extensions = c('Select', 'SearchPanes'),
    selection = 'none'
)
```

is there a way to save the filtered table or the filters used to achieve the users output for further analysis etc in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out:

the rows that were selected via the searchPane are available using : `input$TABLEID_rows_all`

This Input shows you all the rows that are currently in the table.

You can then select these chosen rows and re-render the table:

```
TABLEID[-as.numeric(input$TABLEID_rows_all),]
```